# Mongoose/Mongodb return exactly one of each type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This might be quite specific problem, so I don't know if there's a solution for it supported for it. Basically, I'm doing:

```
Response.find({ title : { "$regex": req.params.response_query, "$options": "i" } }, function (err, foundResponses) {
...}
```

So if I search "There", I'll get something like "There is", "There was", "There can't", etc.

However, there may be many responses that have the same exact title. For example, there might be 5 responses that all have titles "There is no man greater than I." With this code, I'll get all 5 of them back, along with all the others. Is there a way I can only get back one response of each specific title?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.distinct('title')` together with find, like:

```
Response.find({ title : { "$regex": req.params.response_query, "$options": "i" } }).distinct('name').exec(function (err, foundResponses) {...});
```

Comment: What is the performance difference between doing this and holding a separate model that contains only one of each title? They would be queried at different times for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation with $addToSet,

```
Response.aggregate([
   {
      $match:{
         title:{
          "$regex": req.params.response_query, "$options": "i"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:null,
         title:{$addToSet:"$title"}
      }
   }
])

Will return something like : { "_id" : null, "type" : [ "titre 1", "titre 2" ] }
```

Or

```
Response.aggregate([
   {
      $match:{
         title:{
          "$regex": req.params.response_query, "$options": "i"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:"$title"
      }
   }
])
```

Will return something like [{_id:"titre 1"},{_id:"titre 2"},...]